# How many edges can be in an unbalanced bipartite graph of girth $>6$?

Tags: extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, cycles

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a bipartite graph with $n, m$ nodes in its bipartition and girth (shortest cycle length) $>6$.
There is a simple counting argument called the *Moore Bounds* that gives
$$|E| = O\left(n + m + (nm)^{2/3}\right)$$
(proof sketch: pick a random node, run a BFS search to depth $3$, and use the fact that all discovered nodes must be distinct or else we would have a short cycle).

This bound is definitely best possible (up to hidden constant) in a few special cases: when $n=m$ and a few others arising from the incidence graphs of [finite generalized quadrangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_quadrangle#Restrictions_on_parameters).
On the other hand, this is *not* best possible in the entire range of parameters: the [Ruzsa-Szemeredi Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruzsa%E2%80%93Szemer%C3%A9di_problem), plus some light combinatorial massaging, implies that one can shave roughly $\log^*(n)$ when the $n, m$ are very unbalanced (here $\log^*(n)$ is inverse tower function).
So, my question is:

> In what range of tradeoffs between $n, m$ are the Moore Bounds for girth $>6$ known to be tight?

(Trivially they are tight when $n = O(\sqrt{m})$ or $m = O(\sqrt{n})$ since the $+m$ or $+n$ terms dominate, but I am interested more in the intermediate range.)

Comment: This is an extremely difficult open problem. See, for instance, http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/cycles-survey-final-revision.pdf for the state of play.

Comment: Thanks!  Guess that answers it.  That survey is very helpful.